# How to set DNS servers from the command line on macOS Big Sur 11.6 and up

Tags: macos, dns

Before I could do the following:

```sh
sudo networksetup -setdnsservers "$interface" "${servers[@]}"
```

However, since Big Sur 11.6 (perhaps earlier) it returns:

```sh
sudo: networksetup: command not found
```

Apple's guidance is also non-existent:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202516

What is the modern equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it is still there `/usr/sbin/networksetup` however `/usr/sbin` was missing from my `$PATH`